# 502 bad gateway eror when multiple parallel http webrequest are spawned to server

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I am doing stress testing and hence spawned many parallel threads to hit my proxy server with Task.factory but every time after sometime I get 502 bad gateway error.

My code is as below :

```
for (int i = 0; i < tsk.Length; i++)
{
    ds = 0;

    tsk[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew((object obj) =>
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(proxyforDownload);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.Credentials = cc;
        request.Headers.Add("Device", DeviceInf);
        request.Headers.Add("ServerUrl", webdevurl);
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        watch.Stop();
   }, i);
}
```

I am getting bad gateway exception after sometime every time I run the code. Where can be issue.

Comment: after how many attempts do error is shown ?

Comment: Put some efforts to format your question better. It will make it more readable.

Comment: The error is resolved by adding response.close() after every task completion so might be due to non closure of response object but now for large number of threads I am getting unable to coonect to remote server error.

Comment: 1000 parallel threads are working fine but more than that it throws 502 bad gateway. I am hitting the request from the same client (i.e machine)